# Less css loop generates same classes

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to generate this css:

```
img.consults {
    /*some css*/
}
img.coworkers {
    /*some css*/
}
img.dashboard {
    /*some css*/
}
```

with these less css code.

```
@type1: "dashboard";
@type2: "consults";
@type3: "coworkers";

.loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {
    @ctype: "type@{index}";
    @type: e(@@ctype);
    img.@{type} {
        /*some css*/
    }

    .loopingClass (@index - 1);
};

.loopingClass(3);
```

Instead of the desired css code. I get *three* times

```
img.dashboard {
   /*some css*/
}
```

It should start generating `img.consults`, since it is a count down, but I end up with three times `img.dashboard`, which is the first one, so should be generated last. I can't get my head around it! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: FYI-your code outputs as expected by you on LESS 1.4+ when testing on this site: http://less2css.org/. But it does have the issue you mention for LESS 1.3.3 (and presumably below that as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### To Fix But in Version 1.3.2 or 1.3.3

The original code in the question works in LESS 1.4+, but has issues in the two versions previous to that. Those issues can be worked around by nesting the use of the defined variable variable in another mixin call. So this works (for 1.4+ also, but why do more code than necessary if one has upgraded to that):

**LESS**

```css
@type1: "dashboard";
@type2: "consults";
@type3: "coworkers";

.loopingClass(@index) when (@index > 0) {
    @ctype: "type@{index}";
  .setClass(@className) {
     img.@{className} {
         /*some css*/ 
     }
   }
  .setClass(e(@@ctype));
  .loopingClass(@index - 1);
};

.loopingClass(3);
```

**CSS Output**

```css
img.coworkers {
  /*some css*/
}
img.consults {
  /*some css*/
}
img.dashboard {
  /*some css*/
}
```

Comment: Version 1.3.3 was indeed the problem. I've upgraded :)